# Disabling system noise interrupts of music

Tags: audio, music, tasker, spotify

When I'm playing Spotify onto a speaker, it's interrupted by system sounds such as "charging started", "battery low", etc.  Is there any way to prevent these interrupts from occurring while I'm playing songs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. Just turn off audio notifications. That won't have any effect on the media volume.

This will, of course, turn off the phone ringer, which you may not want.

Comment: Is there a way to quickly toggle it, or better yet make it automatically toggle when I start up Spotify?

Comment: Well, you toggle it from the menu you get when you press the power button. To do it automatically you'll need something like Tasker. We have a few Tasker veterans here; perhaps they can suggest a recipe.

Comment: Added "Tasker" tag, feel free to add any other tags that would attract answers to that aspect.. And thanks for the pointers so far

Comment: Should be pretty easy in Tasker: `[Context] App = Spotify, [Task] Silent Mode = On`. Silent mode will automatically be turned off (turning your notification sounds back on) as soon as the Spotify app is left.

Comment: @Mr.Buster is there any way to make silent mode be on even when Spotify is playing music in the background?  When Spotify is up front the context is recognized but when i go to my home screen it's not